Why Swift Task is being suspended after finished?
I found that the Task was being suspended even if the closure of the Task had been done.
So I make a test code like below.
struct ContentView: View {
    let testClass = TestClass()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            testClass.start()
        }, label: {
            Text("button")
        })
    }
}

class TestClass {
    var task: Task<Void, Never>?

    func start() {
        task?.cancel()
        task = Task {
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5_000_000_000)
        }
    }
}

And instrument is showing like below.

My assumption was that the task will have a status like finished, because the closure was done already.
But it's not. It's showing suspended and still alive.
Is this a right concept or I made a wrong example?
I want to get a reference of the task for cancel, and don't want to see a count on Alive Tasks. If I add a code like task =  nil after sleep, it would work as I expected.
Could it be a right workaround?

I used the code for test. I understand the task could be alive because it belongs to View(or somewhere else). But I can't understand why it has the suspended status.

Okay, I am able to reproduce it now. I think this is just because the instance of TestClass still holds a reference to the Task, keeping it "alive".

I don't think there is any other state (out of the ones that Instrument shows) that a completed task can be in. It cannot be "Ending", because that is when the task is about to become un-alive.

It's confusing. It seems that the task is saying "I still have a job to do, so I'm waiting now.". And also I probably saw "Ending" status before in the instruments. Anyways, many thanks for the reply!

The Task still exists because you might inquire about its properties later, even after it is “finished”. Now, your task returns a Void, but imagine a Task that returned a value or throws errors. You can still fetch [try] await task?.value even after the Task is done. But, I agree with you that the choice of the term “suspended“ for a task that has finished, but still exists, is curious.

It feels like there would be a zombie state for this, like Unix processes (probably with a less poetic name). It seems important that this Task should be able to release all memory except for its return state. Does it?

Yeah, I did some quick testing, and locals and captured variables, locals, etc., are correctly released when the closure finishes execution. It appears that the memory required by “finished” tasks is pretty minimal.

If you save the Task in a property, the underlying task still exists (even if it finished running its closure), including the task state (i.e., its value or result).
Now, in your example, the Task returns a Void, so it is hard to see this behavior. But, imagine a Task that returned a value or throws errors. You can still fetch [try] await task?.value even after the Task is done, and you will see the result of the Task closure.
Consider this variation, where we have a separate button that verifies the result of the Task:
import SwiftUI
import os.log

struct ContentView: View {
    let experiment = Experiment()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                Task { await experiment.start() }
            } label: {
                Text("start")
            }

            Button {
                Task { await experiment.verify() }
            } label: {
                Text("verify")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

actor Experiment {
    var task: Task<Int, Error>?
    let signposter = OSSignposter(subsystem: "Experiment", category: .pointsOfInterest)

    func start() async {
        signposter.emitEvent(#function, "start")
        let state = signposter.beginInterval(#function, id: signposter.makeSignpostID())

        task?.cancel()
        let task = Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
            return Int.random(in: 0..<100)
        }
        self.task = task

        do {
            let result = try await task.value
            signposter.endInterval(#function, state, "result = \(result)")
        } catch {
            signposter.endInterval(#function, state, "error = \(error)")
        }

        // Really, we should wrap the above `do`-`catch` in a cancellation handler,
        // as we’re responsible for that when introducing unstructured concurrency,
        // but I was trying to keep it simple. But, you’d probably do something like:
        //
        // await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        //     do {
        //         let result = try await task.value
        //         …
        //     } catch {
        //         …
        //     }
        // } onCancel: {
        //     task.cancel()
        // }
    }

    func verify() async {
        signposter.emitEvent(#function, "start")
        let state = signposter.beginInterval(#function, id: signposter.makeSignpostID())

        guard let task else {
            signposter.endInterval(#function, state, "no task")
            return
        }

        do {
            let result = try await task.value
            signposter.endInterval(#function, state, "result = \(result)")
        } catch {
            signposter.endInterval(#function, state, "error = \(error)")
        }
    }
}

If I profile that (with not only the “Swift Tasks” tool, but also the “Points of Interest” tool that captures my OSSignposter events) and first tap “start” (the first ⓢ signpost) and then tap “verify” before start finishes (the second ⓢ), we see:

So, we see that as soon as the “start” task finishes, the “verify” task does, too. And the “verify” task shows the same result of the Task as we saw in the “start” task. This is interesting, but perhaps unsurprising.
But, if we instead defer the tap on “verify” until the “start” task finishes, we still see the “verify” task show the result for the “finished” task:

Now in this case, the “verify” task runs nearly instantaneously (because it does not have to wait for the “start” Task to finish), but, still, although the “start” Task was already “finished”, the “verify” routine still returns the value of the saved Task.

But, I agree with you that referring to a finished Task as “suspended“ because it still exists, is arguably a curious choice of terminology. But you can also see why it might still be considered “alive”, as it still exists and you can still fetch its value (and or determine if it was cancelled or threw other error) even though its closure has finished execution.

You said:

I want to get a reference of the task for cancel, and don't want to see a count on Alive Tasks. If I add a code like task = nil after sleep, it would work as I expected.
Could it be a right workaround?

Yes, that is a fine solution if you really do not need the task, anymore.
For what it is worth, the amount of memory consumed by this Task that has finished execution is fairly minimal. Any locals or variables captured by the closure are released: It is largely just the task state and its results that are saved once execution finishes.

Many thanks for the answer! By the way, I realized that using task = nil  in Task block could occur data race, because I used class, not actor. Is it right?

Correct. (Using “Strict concurrency check” build setting of “Complete” is a great way of letting the compiler warn you of these data races.)

FWIW, you could also make this Experiment a class isolated to the main actor, too, and that would also eliminate the data race.
